# How can I pass multiple cell values of datagridview from one form to another at same time in C#?

Tags: c#, winforms

I am new to c# and I am using windows forms.
I have `Form1` with `datagridview` and `Form2` with a map on it.

I want to pass unknown number (unlimited number) of `datagridview` cell values from `Form1` to `form2` at same time, that is because I want to show the selected cell values (addresses) of `form1` into `form2` on the map.
I know how to use setters and getters but in this case I think setters and getters will not work because the number of cell values I want to pass to `form2`  is unknown.

Anyone knows how can I pass multiple `datagridview` cell values from `form1` to `form2` at same time? Please help, Thank you

This code in Form1 loops through all the selected rows and I want to pass
`Cells[0].Value` to `form2`:

```
 foreach (DataGridViewRow row in DGV.SelectedRows)
 {
    // here I have to pass all selected row.Cells[0].Value to form2         
 }
```

Comment: Can you pass them as a `List<T>`?  There's not enough info in your question to really help you.

Comment: @Reza Aghaei. data comes from sql server

Comment: @CodingGorilla. I do not know if I can. please ask if I am missing any information

Comment: If you don't know what you can pass or how, I'm not sure any of us can help you.  I _can_ tell you it is definitely possible to pass them as a `List<T>`.

Comment: You can put values in a `List<T>` as mentioned by @CodingGorilla which T is the type of value in column 0.

Comment: @CodingGorilla.  if I know how to pass it I would not ask you...

Comment: the column contains string values

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make a List of string and pass it onto the next form

```
List<string> cellvalueList = new List<string>();

foreach (DataGridViewRow row in DGV.SelectedRows)
{
    // here I have to pass all selected row.Cells[0].Value to form2  
    cellvalueList.Add(row.Cells[0].Value);   
}
```

Now when you invoke next form, you need a property which accepts List there (or pass via constructor). Something like this..

```
Form2 newForm = new Form();
newform.Values = cellvalueList; // this Values is the List<string> property in Form2
newForm.Show();
```

if your form2 is already visible , then you can pass the complete List

```
newform.SetValues(cellvalueList);
```

this SetValues is function in Form2 which takes List of string as parameter

Answer (score 1):

Here is my solution:

```
 List<string> values = new List<string>();
 foreach (DataGridViewRow row in DGV.SelectedRows)
 {
    values.Add(row.Cells[0].Value);         
 }
 myForm2.SetForm1Values(values);
```

There are a few caveats here, the first is you have to be able to get a reference to the instance of your other form (denoted here as `myForm2`).  I used a method called `SetForm1Values` here because you indicated that you weren't sure if a property would work, but indeed a property setter would be just as effective as this method would be.

Answer (score 1):

You can get value of `Cells[0]` of selected rows using such code:

```
List<string> selectedData = this.dataGridView1.SelectedRows.Cast<DataGridViewRow>()
                                .Select(row => (string)row.Cells[0].Value)
                                .ToList();
```

It's equivalent to:

```
List<string> selectedData = new List<string>();
foreach (DataGridViewRow row in this.dataGridView1.SelectedRows)
{
    selectedData.Add((string)row.Cells[0].Value);
}
```